# Is there any way to search through a JSON object for a value?

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a ROBLOX Integrated discord bot with discord.py and have stumbled into an issue with checking if the user is in a group. I have already got a table of all groups and ranks, but have no clue how to iterate through it. The JSON structure is similar to as follows:

```
{
data:[{"group":{id:1,"name":"RobloHunks","memberCount":36351},"role":{"id":169,"name":"--","rank":1}},{"group":{id:2,"name":"LOL","memberCount":157765},"role":{"id":209,"name":"Cheezburgers","rank":1}}]
}
```

In a real example, there would be more than just two groups but I was wondering if there was any way to iterate through and check if the group ID is equal to 1 and then get the role associated with the group? I couldn't find a solution anywhere else.

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: What have you tried and what particular problem do you have? i.e. working with JSON, iterate over list, access dict values, or something else? Not to mention that sample JSON is not valid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, data is a key and the bracket block is a value. That value is a list of dictionaries and the group key corresponds to another dictionary this one containing the id.

So if the json is stored in a variable called x then doing

```
x[‘data’][0][‘group’][‘id’]
```

will get one of them. A loop would be something like

```
for i in range(len(x[‘data’])):
user_id = x[‘data’][i-1][‘group’][‘id’]
if user_id == ‘1’:
   print(x[‘data’][i-1][‘role’])
```

Hopefully this helps. The json would need to be correct though!